# How can we change outlines into shapes in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, stroke

I'm not very comfortable with Illustrator, and I'm stuck on this problem: how can we change from outline strokes to filled shapes?

For example, in this situation, I would like to 'decompose' each shape formed by **different** strokes into a unique shape. It should be simple I think...

[image: example]

Comment: If the curves are separate use shape builder

Comment: Hi Arthur, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I went ahead and edited your question for clarity. If I overstepped and changed things beyond your meaning, feel free to [edit] the question again or roll back my edits. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Live Paint Bucket Tool** -- select all, pick a color, grab the Live Paint Bucket Tool and click where you want fills.

[image]

More information can be found via Adobe TV tutorials: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-live-paint.html

Answer (score 0):

1. to switch from stroke to fill, you can select the shape and then click on this little switch icon (or press shift + x).

   [image]
2. to merge the shapes in one unique shape. You have to select that shapes, then window > pathfinder (or shift+ctrl+f9) and click on the unite icon.

[image]